# How to find warning signs about a company's business practices during a job interview?

Tags: interviewing, work-environment

When going to interviews, I often want to take a peek at how the company works on the inside, but they may not show you everything or want to "keep up appearances" to make them more inviting. Obviously the latter is expected when management wants to really sell the job to you, especially if the company is a well-talked about brand.

But then there have been those times where I take a job and some nasty skeletons come out of the closet.

An actual experience follows: An owner of company A interviewed me and mis-represented his company by showing a large work environment, when in fact all that space belonged to a different company B. He told me A and B are in a partnership so I assumed the space was shared. It was not until a month later I found out that A's owner works for B and subleased a small space from B to run company A on the side. So A's own employees don't represent B, work in a cramped area and receive no company benefits from either A or B, as A is too small of a company to afford fancy things like that.

There wasn't much info about his company online, so it was hard to do research on. How to I look for warning signs like this in the future, before I take the plunge and find out when it's too late?

Comment: When you get the contract, look at who exactly you are signing it with and look up that legal entity online. That would give you an idea...

Comment: to extend on what @Oded said, never sign there.  Always take the contract home and read it carefully first.  Most places will be willing to give you a day or two to look things over.  During this time, conduct your research about the particular company named.

Comment: The contract did state the only the name of Company A. They weren't a registered company back then. I think the first thing that should've been suspect is when the front desk of the office building couldn't find Company A in the directory.

Comment: *There wasn't much info about his company online* that was your first clue.

Comment: @ChrisC So what does any of this have to do with the ethics of their business practices? We are all trying to make money in the game so as long as they don't lie, cheat, steal, harm or break any laws then I don't understand the grudge.  To me the only problem here is that you weren't paying enough attention to what he was clearly telling you and now you find that you don't fit in with the culture of this company.  You didn't necessarily make a mistake, sometimes we give it a go based on limited information and if it doesn't work out then we move on.  This is NOT Company A's fault.

Comment: @maple_shaft I didn't get any of what you are saying from the OP. Company A is a side project of an employee of Company B, and yet the hiring manager for Company A (probably A's owner, B's employee) is representing facilities and perks of Company B as available to and part of Company A. That's not fraud per se, but it's not ethical in the slightest, and yet you somehow expected Chris C to figure this out on his first, escorted visit to the office?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are specific ways to learn meaningful information about company culture in interviews?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/4259/what-are-specific-ways-to-learn-meaningful-information-about-company-culture-in)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have found two things to be extremely helpful:

1. Go to lunch with one or two people form the team you are trying to get hired on.  Ask them as many questions as you can and try to get adequate information on what it would be like to work in that group.  Preferably, this should happen on a separate day from the interview.
2. Ask everyone you meet to list one good thing and one bad thing about working at the company.

On (2) if they can't give you some sort of substantive answer for both pieces, then that should be an instant red flag.  No company is perfect, but the ones trying to improve will be open about their shortcomings and will be able to tell you what they are trying to do to overcome them.

I don't know what your profession is, but adapting your own [Joel Test](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000043.html) during an interview can be extremely helpful as well.  You should have a set list of questions about how the company operates on a day-to-day basis in order to help you make a more informed decision.

Comment: This assumes you have met more than one person...

Comment: @Oded definitely... but I would argue that you shouldn't accept a job after talking to just one person

Comment: Absolutely, but if you read the anecdote from the OP, I get the impression they only ever spoke to one person...

Comment: @Oded I got the same impression, at that point, it's pretty much a gamble whether you will be happy there or not

Comment: @RobertGreiner - I would say that it is a clue that the company is not well managed if the management is not willing to let you meet anyone else but wants to hire you.

Comment: @Chad definitely, I would be thinking "what are you trying to hide from me?"

Comment: I'd assume the OP doesn't have friends at the company, as this wouldn't be an issue if he did.  If you ask the company, they'll send a cheerleader who has already drunk the company cool-aid so to speak.

Answer (score 18):

I always ask the interviewer a question that will send up red flags if there are any:

> If you could change one thing about the company with no possibility of veto, what would it be?

This will usually (>95%) stump the interviewer, and make them think for a minute. I have interviewed a lot in my life, and interview for fun sometimes, and this almost always takes them by surprise. This is useful because most people answering questions on the spot tend towards honesty. Second, this question will almost always elicit what someone considers a **negative** thing about the company, even though you didn't specifically say "what *negative* thing" they would change. You will almost always get red flag answers if there are any big ones. For example, I've heard everything from "team communication really needs improvement" to "the CEO has a temper" to "we spend too much time in meetings". You *will* get red flags before the interviewer even realizes what you're doing. I've even heard some things that would probably be considered against the law. For what it's worth, I interviewed at the Googleplex and six out of my seven interviewers said some variation of "I wish I could work on things that challenge me", with one guy summarizing perfectly by saying "all the low-hanging fruit has been solved and only star engineers get to work on the really hard problems". I would attribute this question as the main reason I didn't accept their offer.

Answer (score 6):

"receive no company benefits from either A or B, as A is too small of a company to afford fancy things like that" - that shouldn't have been a surprise that you learned after you started work. Every job offer I have ever seen for professional position included a description of benefits: vacation, sick , holidays, health insurance, life insurance, education benefits, pension, 401K. Even if they don't provide all the options they do discuss the ones they have.

You need to know things like the number of locations, where the employees work, where is the company HQ. It is OK to work at a customer site, but they should let you know where the rest of the company works. They will be handling HR, purchasing, management...

The actual working conditions will depend on the work location. The customer site may control hardware, software, and office space. The customer site may be more or less impressive then the company site.

You also need to know the other contracts they have to judge their ability to provide a follow on contract if the current contract ends. A small number of contracts, with growth but an inability to keep current employees is a warning flag.

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard, you have to do some scratching yourself, ask *specific* questions, examine their website and previous work (to see the quality of their work). Just don't expect anything until you have worked for them for a while. I went through a similar experience. I guess we both learned our lesson.

But in general, they way you are being dealt with during the interview phase should give you an idea of how you will be treated later. In my case, I was asked to start "like, next week". That was the beginning of general disrespect trend, such as receiving an SMS on Friday night asking me to show up for work the next morning (Saturday was normally off). In your case the company (supposedly a big company) not having a website might have been a clue.

Comment: I agree with the SMS message being an issue but what's wrong with being asked if you can start next week? Trying to figure out how soon employees can start and getting them into place as quickly as possible is fairly standard I would say.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I'm assuming you have no friends or acquaintances that work there, and must expand your network.

From your post, I'm assuming this company's office is small, and they share the building with several other companies.  If this is the case, look for events happening in/near the building, professional events being best.

Start asking at those events about this company.  Even if you do not meet someone who works there, someone will likely know people who do.  You can ask them about the company.