# How to determine if company is too "broken" to fix problems?

Tags: relationships, technology

I accepted an IT job at a well-known company in the media industry.  The company itself is doing well financially, mostly due to acquisitions and programming decisions.

The business is supposed to work alongside their designated IT area in a partnership, but the arrangement has been failing since before I got there (I became aware recently).  The business owns the application (third-party cloud based) that IT supports, meaning they don't rely on us for anything.

We are often told about projects by the business after they've already been started or even completed. It's been a struggle to even get work on our plates and for the last month at least, I've literally had nothing to do.  My direct supervisor is in the same boat and has raised issue to her boss, but the answer is typically "this is how it is."

I don't know whether this is something that I should expect to change or if it means the company is too broken to fix it.  What are the steps I can take to try to find out?

Comment: this question looks pretty much the same as [What are specific ways to learn meaningful information about company culture in interviews?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/4259/168)

Answer (score 1):

> I don't know whether this is something that I should expect to change
>   or if it means the company is too broken to fix it. What are the steps
>   I can take to try to find out?

Since the only people who can assess the situation fully are within the company, your solution is to "ask around".

Ask coworkers, your boss, people in your group and outside of your group - particularly those who have been around for a while. Find out:

- Has it always been like this?
- Is anything getting better?
- Is anyone doing anything to make it better?
- Does anyone have any hope?