# How do you ask in an interview if there will advancement opportunities if you do not have a college degree

Tags: interviewing

How do you ask in an interview if you will be qualified for an advancement in the future if you do not have a college degree? I know some companies do not let people without degrees advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are specific ways to learn meaningful information about company culture in interviews?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/4259/what-are-specific-ways-to-learn-meaningful-information-about-company-culture-in)

Comment: Valid question.  Buddy of mine got a good job at a big company and later found out he could only get one more grade (small promotion) without a degree.

Comment: @mcknz I would agree if that question had not been closed not constructive.  This question on the contrary is answerable and focused.  For that reason I believe it should be left open

Answer (score 5):

I would think a generic "Once hired, would I be able to work my way up through the ranks of the company?" or "What are the long term prospects for this position?" would suffice. This shows that you're interested in staying with the company for the long haul and you're interested in improving yourself--both good in most interviewers' minds. The only risk is that they'll say you can earn promotions, then never promote you (which is an issue for everyone, regardless of degrees).

Comment: "The only risk is that they'll say you can earn promotions, then never promote you" -- describes the vast majority of employers.