# How to find out if work location is flexible at potential company?

Tags: interviewing, job-search, telecommute, employment, remote-work

I'm starting the interview process with a company & position that I'm very interested in. However, for personal reasons it's extremely important to me that I should be able to work remotely occasionally without having to take the day off.

How can I find this out during the interview process, without sounding like I won't show up to the office every day?

**EDIT** - A related point is that I might one day want to switch to fully-remote. At some companies, this is completely out of the question. Is there a way to find out if this is even an option for one day?

**NOTE** - This is different from [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/4259) since my focus is specifically on remote working, not about general culture. That other question does not address what I'm asking here.

Comment: When you're being interviewed by different employees. You could ask the following question: Describe a typical week/day here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are specific ways to learn meaningful information about company culture in interviews?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/4259/what-are-specific-ways-to-learn-meaningful-information-about-company-culture-in)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is perfectly fine to ask this during an interview, and working from home is becoming more common now, especially for workers with kids at home or other responsibilities.

At some point during the interview they will usually ask you if you have any questions. This is a good time to ask some questions, such as "will I usually be working from this office", "what's the parking / public transport like", "can I work from home when I need to xyz", "what are your policies around flexible hours" and so on. These are normal questions to ask.

As a bonus, asking these kinds of questions demonstrates that you're already thinking about the practicalities of working there, which means you're interested in them.

Comment: I think this is a good answer but I would advise caution with word choice for xyz in the sentence *"can I work from home when I need to xyz"* - you don't want to come off sounding like someone who is going to abuse WFH for personal reasons. Working from home is for *working* not for dealing with plumbers, caring for a family member, or whatever. Some employers may be OK with occasional flexibility for these things but it's probably better to just ask what the employer's policy is versus suggesting a reason why you may want to do it that may sound like you're eager to take advantage.

Answer (score 5):

> How can I find this out during the interview process, without sounding
>   like I won't show up to the office every day?

"Is there a remote work option?"

"Does the company have a work from home policy?"

Either of these will do the trick. Neither of those make you sound like you won't show up in the office.